# Meteor bundle error (Windows)

Tags: windows, meteor

Meteor 0.3.7 via Windows installer
I have exacly same error in Windows 8 and Windows Server 2008
Steps:
1) Install Meteor
2) create app
3) bundle
4) error

See screen shot for details

[image: error]

Update: bad news. Bundling is not supported yet in windows version of meteor.

Comment: Exactly, bundling isn't supported yet.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two separate issues here. The first is that Meteor is failing to run "tar". Do you have the "tar" program installed? What happens when you run "tar" at the prompt?

The second appears to be an issue with Meteor's files.rm_recursive function. It is trying to delete the C:\files2\ddd.meteor\local\build_tar\bundle\server directory, but that directory is not empty, even though it already tried to delete all the files in it. Can you look in that directory and see what is left (including perhaps files that might be hidden by default)? I'm not enough of a Windows expert to know the right command here. For example, I know on a Mac that this directory will have a ".bundle_version.txt" file in it; maybe the rm_recursive function on Windows misses deleting that file?

Comment: I`ve installed GNU tar and added to windows path variable. So now I can reach it from prompt. But meteor stil shows 'couldn`t run tar'. And what is about ../local/build_tar/bundle/server directory. It contains node_modules directory with all meteor node modules. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you update the question with the current error you get now that you've installed tar? (Or whatever is appropriate for stackoverflow; I'm new here.) And if you are still getting the rm_recursive error, maybe run ls -laR local/build_tar/bundle/server, or whatever the equivalent on Windows is (the 'a' shows dotfiles, the R is recursive).

Comment: Thanks, David. I`ve contacted @TomWij, who created windows installer for meteor. It just does not support bundling yet.

Comment: What about deploying a bundle into a Node.js server on Windows?